# Executing UNIX command using Java

Tags: java, unix

I am trying to run Unix find command from Java but it is giving me below error . 
Please suggest right approach on this -

> java -cp automation.jar com.amex.scoring.dao.HiveDAO
>
> /bin/sh: find /axp/rim/nemo/dev/logs  -type f -mtime -5 -exec ls {} \;: No such file or directory

**Java Code**

```
private static final String COMMAND = "find /axp/rim/nemo/dev/logs  -type f -mtime -5 -exec ls {} \\;";
private static final String SHELL_NAME = "/bin/sh";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(SHELL_NAME,COMMAND);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    final Process process = pb.start();
    final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jens , sorry did not get you . where do you want me to add full path ?

Comment: to the find command and i think also for the ls command

Comment: Unnecessary double escape: `\\;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See it :

```
package com.raj.shell;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ExecuteShellComand {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecuteShellComand obj = new ExecuteShellComand();

        String output = obj.executeCommand();

        System.out.println(output);

    }

    private String executeCommand() {

        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        try {

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "cd && cat test.txt | grep Hello"});
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader
                    = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output.toString();

    }

}
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation; to point out why your input is working; and his is not. Just dropping code doesn't make a good answer.